# Non-exhaustive pattern while iterating matrix

Tags: haskell, recursion, matrix

So I'm very new to haskell, and I'm not very sure how to deal with this error when iterating over a matrix. I'm guessing there's a case I'm not considering, but I can't figure out what it is. I've got two functions, one that turns a list into a string and another that turns a matrix into a string. These are my two functions:

```
listToString :: [Int] -> String 
listToString [] = "\n"
listToString (x:xs) = show x ++ " " ++ listToString xs 

matToString :: [[Int]] -> String 
matToString [[]] = ""
matToString (y:x:xs)) = listToString y ++  matToString (x:xs)
```

listToString works fine but matToString does not. I was wondering if someone could help me out with this. I've been having a hard time understanding Haskell, since I've never programmed in a functional programming language before, or well at least not one that is purely functional.

Comment: matToString [[]] = "" change to matToString [] = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive case covers every list with at least two arguments, so that's cool. The problem is your base case—it only covers the case of a list with exactly one element, itself the empty list.

Add this to the very top of your file: `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}`. That should give you a detailed compiler warning indicating which pattern(s) is/are missing.

Comment: That's a very useful tool, thanks. Look forward to learning more about haskell, they say its very useful for what it does, even though I've heard some people say no one uses it for anything.

Comment: @Argus, those people are wrong. It's not exactly big in industry, but it's around, and seems to be growing in popularity.

Comment: Yes, and an example  I've heard of is using haskell as a server side language, which I thought was pretty interesting.